# Showing that spectrum of tensor product of linear operators having respectively $\{μ_i\}$ and $\{λ_j\}$ as eigenvalues is $\{μ_iλ_j\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification, tensor-products

I'm hoping to get a clue to show the following problem, for which I only have an intuition:

Considering a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and operators $φ:V→V$ and $ψ:U→U$, I would like to show that the if the characteristic polynomials of $φ$ and $ψ$ are both completely decomposable with $\{μ_i\}$ and $\{λ_j\}$ the eigenvalues of $φ$ and $ψ$ respectively, then the spectrum of $φ⊗ψ$ is $\{μ_iλ_j\}$.

The problem is that I don't know many properties of tensor product,so even if it's clear for me that the eigenvalues $\{μ_i\}$ and $\{λ_j\}$ will all be present in the spectrum of $φ⊗ψ$ under product, since $φ⊗ψ$ has same rank as $rk(φ)rk(ψ)$, I'm not sure how I can prove this with tensor product.

Could anyone give me a hint how to start or what should be used ? In terms of tensor product

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following solutions with your advice:

Thanks to Kronecker product we can represent th matrix of $φ⊗ψ$ by the matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
a_{11}b_{11} & \cdots & a_{11}b_{1m} & \cdots & a_{1n}b_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}b_{1m}\\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
a_{11}b_{q1} & \cdots & a_{11}b_{qm} & \cdots & a_{1n}b_{q1} & \cdots & a_{1n}b_{qm}\\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
a_{p1}b_{11} & \cdots & a_{p1}b_{1m} & \cdots & a_{pn}b_{11} & \cdots & a_{pn}b_{1m}\\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
a_{p1}b_{q1} & \cdots & a_{p1}b_{qm} & \cdots & a_{pn}b_{q1} & \cdots & a_{pn}b_{qm}\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Where $\varphi = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
a_{p1} & \cdots & a_{pn}\end{array}\right)$ and $\psi = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1m}\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
b_{q1} & \cdots & b_{qm}
\end{array}\right)$

Therefore if I consider arbitrary eigenvectors $u$ and $v$ of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ respectively, I sould have $\varphi u = \mu u$ and $\psi v = \lambda v$, by definition. THis would give us, for the tensor product $φ⊗ψ$:

$(φ⊗ψ)(u\otimes v) = \mu\lambda(u\otimes v)$, meaning that if $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are respectively eigenvalues of $\varphi$ and $\psi$, then the product $\mu\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $φ⊗ψ$.

Since we are given the eigenvalues of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as respectively $\{\mu_i\}$ and $\{\lambda_j\}$, it follows that:

$(φ⊗ψ)(u_1\otimes v_1) = \mu_1\lambda_1(u_1\otimes v_1)$

$(φ⊗ψ)(u_2\otimes v_2) = \mu_2\lambda_2(u_2\otimes v_2)$

$\vdots$

$(φ⊗ψ)(u_i\otimes v_j) = \mu_i\lambda_j(u_i\otimes v_j)$

Hence this proves that the spectrum of $(φ⊗ψ)$ is indeed $\{\mu_i\lambda_j\}$.

Is this true and enough?

Comment: The tensor product of operators act on the tensor product of spaces. If you want to investigate its spectrum, use the tensor product of the respective eigenvectors

Comment: If you identify your operators with their matrices, see "Kronecker product".

Comment: Okey thank you both i will try that to start!

Comment: I tried something, can you take alook at the edit of my post @Exodd?

Comment: And @JeanMarie?

Comment: Yes, that's exact, you have very well catched the concepts and techniques ! If you want, in some hours, I can give you hints for some applications.

Comment: That's very nice of you ! maybe one, as a start :)

Comment: actually, it is not enough... you should also show that there aren't any other eigenvalues

Comment: Mmh that's true @Exodd, but do you have an idea how to do this ?

Comment: If $\phi,\psi$ are diagonalizable operators (for example, selfadjoint), then it is easy, because the eigenvectors you found are actually a basis of the whole tensor space, meaning there couldn't be others. 
Otherwise it gets messy

Comment: Uh, sorry, actually, it is not so messy once you think about Jordan forms. If $\varphi = MJ_1M^{-1}$ and $\psi = NJ_2N^{-1}$, then $\varphi \otimes \psi = (M\otimes N)(J_1\otimes J_2) (M\otimes N)^{-1}$, so its eigenvalues are the same as the ones of $J_1\otimes J_2$, but this is an upper triangular matrix, so you can read the eigenvalues on the diagonal. You will find, with respective multiplicities, exactly $\mu_i\lambda_j$

Comment: Indeed we must check there are no other eigenvalues, thank you for noticing that @Exodd !

Comment: $\text{trace}\Big(\big(\phi \otimes \psi\big)^k\Big)=\text{trace}\Big(\phi^k \otimes \psi^k\Big)=\text{trace}\Big(\phi^k\Big)\cdot  \text{trace}\Big(\psi^k\Big)$  gives an easy proof over $\mathbb C$